# Unpacking elements of a numpy matrix

Tags: numpy, matrix, element

I am trying to build a matrix from a text file that has entries as:

```
  45.0  0.00173  -0.0227 ...
  45.07 0.00173  -0.00227 ...
  .
  .
  .
```

So far, I've read the file lines:

```
with open(os.path.join(dirs,fil),"r") as deck:
            deck_lines=deck.readlines()
```

And got my required rows using:

```
 freq_chan = deck_lines[6+int(no_nodes):len(deck_lines)]
```

And got the values into a matrix:

```
freq_chan = np.matrix([i.split() for i in freq_chan]).astype(np.float)
```

But when I try to extract columns from the matrix, it seems that each element is read as a matrix:

```
  values = freq_chan[:,0]
  print(values)
```

produces:

```
[[45.0]
[45.07]
 .
 .
 .]]
```

But what I want is [45.0, 45.07, ...]

Is there a way to unpack the elements, perhaps using a for loop.

Comment: Most operations on an `np.matrix` return another matrix, which will also be 2d.  Why not use `np.array`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your file is text with some simple formatting, you should be able to use [`np.loadtxt()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html).